# Are there other Gringotts branches in the world beside the one in Diagon Alley?

Tags: harry-potter, gringotts

We know about at least one Gringotts in the world, the one in Diagon Alley.There is possibly one in Egypt as Bill Weasley work as a Gringotts curse-breaker there. Apart from Bill's job,is there any other evidence that other Gringotts exist throughout the world.In Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Hagrid says that Gringotts is the only place to store your gold.He may mean in the UK or in the whole world.

I wonder if the Gringotts in Diagon Alley is the only Gringotts in the entire world?

Comment: Even if you just have a theory about this I will happily read it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a dupe. The answer in the other question isn't great but I'll have a go at giving it a better answer.

Comment: I'm working on making original questions that DON'T get called dupes by death-eaters ok.

Comment: @Hermione, please keep in mind that we *like* duplicate questions, because they help people find the already existing answers.  Also, welcome!

Comment: @HarryJohnston - to be fair, the names add an extra layer of hilarity in this case :)

Comment: The dark lord himself is not a death eater

Comment: I know  ok I was just saying